# How can I create a table in SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have prepared a code to create a database as well as table in SQLITE ANDROID STUDIO, but I am getting error in SQL statement.

Image of error is here :- [ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXGNB.png)

```
package com.example.thakkar.registration;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.View;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASAE_NAME="student.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="student_table";
public static final String COL_1="NAME";
public static final String COL_2="EMAIL";
public static final String COL_3="PASSWORD";



public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASAE_NAME, null, 1);

    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table"+ TABLE_NAME+ "(NAME TEXT,EMAIL TEXT,PASSWORD TEXT)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST"+ TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you tag the question with Visual Studio if you use Android Studio?

Comment: sorry my mistake

Comment: Also if you're not forced to create your own SQLite database, I'd suggest you look into [Room Database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/) which is one of the amazing architecture components provided by google :)

Comment: Mind your **SPACES**! `db.execSQL("create table"+ TABLE_NAME+ "(NAME TEXT,EMAIL TEXT,PASSWORD TEXT)");` and `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST"+ TABLE_NAME);`

Comment: @wax911 thank you for your great advice!

Comment: @KlingKlang thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to separate `table` with space before `TABLE_NAME`,
Something like ,

```
db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME+ "(NAME TEXT,EMAIL TEXT,PASSWORD TEXT)");
```

Also do the same in `onUpgrade()` method,

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
```

Comment: Gotcha , Done as per instructions ! ;)

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!